# C program to copy one binary tree to another

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-tree

Can any one help me with a C program to copy one binary tree to another binary tree?

I am okay with either algorithm or C functions so that I can implement them.

Thank you :)

Comment: Algorithm: To copy a subtree somewhere: Create a new element there; copy the left subtree as the left child of the copy; copy the right subtree as the right child of the copy. -- is this what you wanted to hear?

Comment: Your problem is about code implementation? Maybe , you can paste your code here.

Comment: @JanDvorak, well, to some extent yes.. but i would like to know how it can be achieved ? and is merging two binary trees are same as that of copying ? what are the things that i have to keep in mind while copying a tree to another ?

Comment: Then I'm afraid you didn't specify your question well enough. Note that with any kind of merging other than "append anywhere", your "as a child" clause is broken or at least misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the tree you want added is a proper subset (no overlaps) and the tree doesn't have to be balanced, you can just append its root node to the correct insertion point. By that, I mean something like:

```
  10
 /  \
1    70
 *
  5
 / \
2   7
```

where you can create a link on the right of the `1` to attach to the `5`. This will work because the entire sub-tree slots in between `1` and `10` (which is what I meant by "no overlaps").

In fact, if the tree also isn't even *sorted,* you can just attach the root node to *any* leaf that you want:

```
  40
 /  \
1    10
       *
        5
       / \
      8   789
```

In that case, overlaps are not a concern since the tree is not sorted so it's a safe bet to assume you don't care about order.

However, if you have a balanced *and* sorted tree, your best bet is probably to traverse one of the trees and use the `insert` method to add each value found to the *other* tree.

That will both properly combine "overlapping" trees and keep the target tree balanced if necessary. So, using the first example above, you'd get something like:

```
     7
    / \
   /   \
  2     10
 / \      \
1   5      70
```

The "algorithm" then becomes something like:

```
def copyTree (source, destination):
    item = source.first()
    while item != none_left:
        destination.insert (item.value)
        item = source.next (item)
```

That way, you don't have to worry about whether the attachment will be problematic because the `insert` method of the destination tree will automatically do the right thing (sort, balance, etc).

Comment: +1 didn't think about preserving the tree invariants. The question said "as a child".

Comment: @paxdiablo, At least you got me right ! Thanks a lot for the answer and time.. will try implementing now and get back here if i could do it..

Comment: @Paxdiablo i am looking forward for your comment now..

Comment: @Dodger, given this question was accepted and closed and your proposed edits were actually a rather massive change, you will get more responses if you post that edit as a totally different question. People can't post answers on closed questions so editing it here is futile. Have rolled back but you can examine edit history to copy your edit into a new question. That way, you'll get the entire swarm looking at it, not just me. And, as good as I am, it just _may_ be that the swarm is better :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo, yes, i will post as a different question..

Comment: @paxdiablo, Here is the new post , please take a look :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827428/c-program-to-copy-one-binary-search-tree-to-another