# C Program to copy one binary search tree to another

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-search-tree

So, here i have come up with Binary search tree prgram, where i am creating 2 binary trees tmp and tmp2, where i am trying to copy whole tmp2 to tmp, the node which is taken as input from user. But i am getting some segmentation fault, also i am not so sure if the logic is right.
Here is the whole program, please lemme know where is it going wrong in t_cpy() or please just fix it for me..

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node
{
int data;
struct node *rlink;
struct node *llink;
}*tmp=NULL,*tmp2=NULL,*tmp3=NULL;

typedef struct node NODE;

NODE *create();

void inorder(NODE *);
void insert(NODE *);
void t_cpy(NODE *,NODE *);

int main()
{

int n,m;
do
{
    printf("\n1.create tree 1\n2.Insert element to tree1\n3.create tree 2\n4.Insert element to tree2\n5.Inorder tree1\n6.Inorder tree2\n7.Copy tree2 to tree1\n8.exit\n\n");
    printf("\nEnter ur choice: ");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    switch(m)
    {
        case 1: tmp=create();
                break;
        case 2: insert(tmp);
                break;
        case 3: tmp2=create();
                break;
        case 4:
                insert(tmp2);
                break;
        case 5: printf("\n\nInorder Tree1: ");
                inorder(tmp);
                break;
        case 6: printf("\n\nInorder Tree 2: ");
                inorder(tmp2);
                break;
        case 7: t_cpy(tmp,tmp2);

                break;
        case 8: return(0);
    }
}while(n!=8);
return(0);
}
void insert(NODE *root)
{
    NODE *newnode;
    if(root==NULL)
    {
        newnode=create();
        root=newnode;
    }
    else
    {
        newnode=create();
        while(1)
        {
            if(newnode->data<root->data)
            {
                if(root->llink==NULL)
                {
                    root->llink=newnode;
                    break;
                }
                root=root->llink;
            }
            if(newnode->data>root->data)
            {
                if(root->rlink==NULL)
                {
                    root->rlink=newnode;
                    break;
                }
                root=root->rlink;
            }
        }
    }
}

NODE *create()
{
    NODE *newnode;
    int n;
    newnode=(NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    printf("\n\nEnter the Data ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    newnode->data=n;
    newnode->llink=NULL;
    newnode->rlink=NULL;
return(newnode);
}


void t_cpy(NODE *t1,NODE *t2)
{
    int val,opt=0;
    NODE *temp;
    if(t1==NULL || t2==NULL)
    {
        printf("Can not copy !\n");
    }
    inorder(t1);

    printf("\nEnter the node value where tree 2 should be copied\n");
    scanf("%d",&val);
    temp=t1;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        if(val<temp->data)
            temp=temp->llink;
        else
            temp=temp->rlink;
    }
    if(temp->llink!=NULL || temp->rlink!=NULL)
        printf("Not possible to copy tree to this node\n");
    else
    {
        printf("Copy tree to \n 1.Left Node \n 2.Right Node\n Enter your choice : ");
        scanf("%d",&opt);
        if(opt==1)
        {
            temp->llink=t2;
        }
        else if(opt==2)
        {
            temp->rlink=t2;
        }
        else
            printf("Invalid choice\n");
    }
    printf("Tree1 after copying is\n");
    inorder(temp);
}


void inorder(NODE *tmp)
{
    if(tmp!=NULL)
    {
        inorder(tmp->llink);
        printf("%d",tmp->data);
        inorder(tmp->rlink);
    }
}
```

EDIT : Thanks to @xaxxon , who helped me with this.
Just update the while to make it work :

```
while(temp!=NULL&&temp->data!=val)
{
    if(val<temp->data)
        temp=temp->llink;
    else
        temp=temp->rlink;
    if(temp->llink==NULL && temp->rlink==NULL && temp->data!=val)
    { 
        printf("Invalid Node value entered !\n");
        //break;
        return 0;
    }
```

and, Now it works fine for if entered value is present in the tree.

Thanks :)

Comment: what is the order of input that causes the crash?

Comment: its nt order of input.. i guess i am having the logic wrong in t_cpy()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Among other possible problems, you traverse temp until it is null, and on the next line you dereference it.

```
while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        if(val<temp->data)
            temp=temp->llink;
        else
            temp=temp->rlink;
    }
    if(temp->llink!=NULL || temp->rlink!=NULL)
        printf("Not possible to copy tree to this node\n");
```

You most likely mean to break out of this loop if val == temp->data, but you don't.  Also, you still need to check to see if temp is null after the loop in case you didn't find val in your tree.  Most likely you just meant to say:

```
    if(temp==NULL)
        printf("Not possible to copy tree to this node\n");
```

Also, you can't ask which side of the found node the user wants to copy a tree to.  If you have a binary search tree, it has to be the side where the value should go.  If you say to copy it to the right side, but all the values are less than the node, it's no longer a BST.  In fact, you can't even ask where the value should go and still have a binary search tree.  Each node has to be traversed from the root of the tree you want to put the other tree into to maintain the BST mechanics.

Comment: yea, i need to break out of loop when va;l==temp->data and also then attach/copy other tree to that node..  
so what should be the condition in the while() loop ?

Comment: Actually, read my further updates.  You're not looking for specific crash bugs right now -- your whole program is wrong.  We can chat about it if you want.  I have a few minutes.  I'll teach you about binary search trees.

Comment: i wish i could ! i am in college lab right nw, and so i am afraid i can chat right nw :( Would be happy if you could fix the issue here, and if u could explain i ll follow it up..

Comment: well i am new to stackoverflow :(

Comment: yea :( any ways., i ll reach that point soon :) btw, i would be really helped if you could solve this problem for me.. need for internal assessments :( tiered of tracing it actually.. not so good with logics :(

Comment: can we have a discusssion/chat some where else  ? gtalk  ?

Comment: Dodger and I chatted and he's got a better idea what he needs to do now.

Answer (score 0):

When you first use `insert(tmp)` the value of tmp does not change after you call `insert()`.  Pass the address of tmp to `insert()`, using a *root within it instead of root.

Comment: i am not having issues in creating/inserting right now.. i traversed it after insertion and works fine .. just issue is with the t_cpy()

Comment: can you upvote the question so he gets enough reputation that I can chat with him and explain this?

Comment: Yeah, it seems like this would make the insert never work, as you'd never know where the node you inserted was and never have a tree root